# References for biased forecasts from EGARCH

Tags: volatility, time-series, garch, reference-request

A few months ago I've read somewhere that although the exponential GARCH model may lead to higher BIC values in comparison to other extensions of the GARCH family (GARCH, GJR-GARCH, TGARCH, ...), volatility forecasting under this model may lead to biased results. I'm trying to find a trustworthy source (an academic paper) which could back this, but so far I've found

- this [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/assess-egarch-forecast-bias-through-simulations.html) page which indirectly tells me that results are biased,
- [this](https://core.ac.uk/download/files/153/6350116.pdf) 2010 working paper which hasn't been published in any journal, and
- some bachelor/master theses that report this info without backing it with an academic source.

And as you may imagine, I can't (or better, I don't want to) quote other students' theses in my own thesis.

Do you know of any published work which proves this claim? Or a reliable source which suggests why the EGARCH shouldn't be used for forecasting?

Comment: In general, *higher* BIC values indicate *inferior* models. I think EGARCH has some poor properties; you could check the papers about log-GARCH models by [Genaro Sucarrat](http://www.sucarrat.net/), I think he contrasts log-GARCH with EGARCH and mentions what's wrong with EGARCH. [Here](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/67140/1/MPRA_paper_67140.pdf) and [here](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/51783/1/MPRA_paper_51783.pdf) you may find just a small remark that proving properties of QML estimator for EGARCH models is difficult and has not been done except for the most basic case.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that, I meant higher BIC values in absolute terms (being negative, of course I meant lower values). But thanks for the links here and in your answer below, I'll check them out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a couple of papers mentioning bias of EGARCH:

- Demos, Antonis, and Dimitra Kyriakopoulou. "Bias correction of ML and QML estimators in the EGARCH (1, 1) model." *Preprint* (2010).
- Deb, Partha. "Finite sample properties of maximum likelihood and quasi-maximum likelihood estimators of EGARCH models." *Econometric Reviews* 15.1 (1996): 51-68.

The first one is the same as you mention, so it is of no extra use to you. Probably the second one could be more useful. Unfortunately, I do not have access to it, so I cannot see what is inside.

Answer (score 0):

This does nor address your question directly, but is somehow related

*"We find no evidence that a GARCH(1,1) is outperformed by more sophisticated models in our analysis of exchange rates, whereas the GARCH(1,1) is clearly inferior to models that can accommodate a leverage effect in our analysis of IBM returns."*

Peter R. Hansen, Asger Lunde, **A forecast comparison of volatility models: does anything beat a GARCH(1,1)?** *JAE*, Volume 20, Issue 7, December 2005, Pages 873–889

Comment: See also Alexios Ghalanos, the author of "rugarch", "rmgarch" and several other R packages, challenging this view in his blog post ["Does anything NOT beat GARCH(1,1)"](http://unstarched.net/2013/01/).